# Want a pandas Series of Trips Completed to count(Request) ratio for each hour as index for the given dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

The link to the dataset: 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/19P0Trh_vJ2UuC9qZi7xLL_ZFTeKLTvWR/view?usp=sharing'

What I want: To plot seperate graphs for every 'Status' value and 'Pickup point' combo with hours (0-23) on x axis and (Count(Trips Completed)/Count(Requests id)) ratio on y axis. That is, Airport->City Trip Completed Ratio will be 1 graph and City->Airport Trip Completed Ratio will be another. Similarly for other Status values too (Cancelled and No Cars Available).

What I tried: I tried to create a new column Trip Completed Ratio where I will put calculated ratio values corresponding to the hour value in that row.
I know how to calculate the above ratio for each hour separately

```
y = df[df['Req_hour']==0] #for ratio at 00 hours
ratio = y[y['Status'] == 'Trip Completed'].shape[0] / y.shape[0]
print(ratio)
```

But this is too time consuming.
Is there a way where I can create 3 new columns in the dataframe (one for each unique Status column value, ie., 'Trips_Completed Ratio', 'Cancelled Ratio' and 'No Cars Available Ratio') and for every corresponding hour I write the ratio value for that hour for that column.

P.S. Please provide your answers in pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Data manipulation**

```
agg = df.pivot_table(index=["Req_hour", "Status", "Pickup point"], values=["Request id"], aggfunc="count").rename(columns={"Request id": "Count"}).reset_index()
hr_totals = df[["Req_hour", "Request id"]].groupby(["Req_hour"]).count().rename(columns={"Request id": "Total"}).reset_index()
merged = agg.merge(hr_totals, on="Req_hour")
merged['Ratio'] = merged['Count'] / merged['Total']
```

**Output**

```
Req_hour    Status  Pickup point    Count   Total   Ratio
0   0   Cancelled   City    3   99  0.030303
1   0   No Cars Available   Airport 30  99  0.303030
2   0   No Cars Available   City    26  99  0.262626
3   0   Trip Completed  Airport 23  99  0.232323
4   0   Trip Completed  City    17  99  0.171717
5   1   Cancelled   City    4   85  0.047059
6   1   No Cars Available   Airport 29  85  0.341176
7   1   No Cars Available   City    27  85  0.317647
8   1   Trip Completed  Airport 13  85  0.152941
9   1   Trip Completed  City    12  85  0.141176
```

**Plotting**

Plot the data in subplots by pickup point, x axis is the hour and the status is is the bar color.

```
sns.catplot(x="Req_hour", y="Ratio", hue="Status", row="Pickup point", data=merged, kind="bar", size=6, aspect=2)
```

[image: sns plot]

Comment: Kind of. How do I plot a sns.barplot() for each combination of 'Pickup point' and 'Status' where x axis is hours and y axis is the ratio?

Comment: @SharadSharma Updated with a plot! mark the answer as correct if it helped

Comment: Dude, the answer is gold. I learnt pivot_table and groupby in the class and did a few practice questions on it but this is my first assignment and couldn't find a way to approach it. But your answer has made so many things clear. Thank you so much for the answer. Consider your today's good deed done.